# Trying to simplify this

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

How do I simplify this into a formula?

**Note:** $z,g,o,x,p,b,c,f,y$ - are all multiplicative constants

I have:

$$n(1)=z\left(gox^0+p\left(\frac{b}c\right)-fy^0\right)$$

$$n(3)=z\left(gox^2+p\left(\frac{b+n(1)+n(2)}c\right)-fy^2\right)$$

$$n(4)=z\left(gox^3+p\left(\frac{b+n(1)+n(2)+n(3)}c\right)-fy^3\right)$$

So I figure:

$$n(r)=z\left(gox^{r-1}+p\left(\frac{b+n(1)+n(2)+n(3)+\cdots+n(r-1)}c \right)-fy^{r-1}\right)$$

But I am having trouble simplifying this into a formula...

How would one go about simplifying this?

Any and all help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:** $z,g,o,x,p,b,c,f,y$ - are all multiplicative constants

Comment: Welcome to this fantastic site ! May be, just the sigma notation.

Comment: Thank you! Are you suggesting $\sum_{r=1}^{r-1} n_{(r)}$, if not, how so?

Comment: What are $z$ and $p$? If these are arbitrary functions, there's essentially nothing to simplify further. If these are just multiplicative constants, there might be something (and then what is $go$?). If these are continuous (or more specific) functions, and there are some other conditions... In addition to that, please explain the domain of all the variables. Currently it's hardly possible to say anything.

Comment: z,g,o,x,p,b,c,f, and y are all multiplicative constants that can be any real number. Thank you for the critique and consideration, how would you continue?

Comment: The summation index should not be r.  The sum should be$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}n(k)$.

Comment: thank you for this revision

Comment: Let $\,m_r=n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_r\,$ then $m_r-m_{r-1}=z\left(gox^{r-1}+\frac{p}{c}\left(b+m_{r-1}\right)-fy^{r-1}\right)$ $\iff m_r=\left(\frac{zp}{c}+1\right)m_{r-1}+zgo\,x^{r-1}-zf\,y^{r-1}+\frac{zpb}{c}\,$. This is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence, however the particular solution is not necessarily obvious.

Comment: @dxiv i dont understand, could you share the solution?

Comment: @metamorphy how would you resume?

Comment: @user3147682 It's just writing the same recurrence in terms of $\,m_r\,$ instead:

$$\overbrace{\;\;n(r)\;\;}^{m(r) - m(r-1)}=z\left(gox^{r-1}+p\left(\frac{b+\overbrace{n(1)+n(2)+n(3)+\cdots+n(r-1)}^{m(r-1)}}c \right)-fy^{r-1}\right)$$

This gives an arguably simpler form after rearranging, however, as I wrote, it does not directly lead to a closed form solution.

Comment: @user3147682 I did in my answer - it was not too hard ;)

Comment: @dxiv how did you get $(\frac{zp}{c}+1)$

Comment: @user3147682 Collect both terms in $\,m(r-1)\,$ on the RHS.

Comment: @dxiv collect which terms?

Comment: @user3147682 See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906408/trying-to-simplify-this?noredirect=1#comment6006722_2906408). You have a $\,-m(r-1)\,$ on the LHS, which becomes $\,+m(r-1)\,$ after you move it to the RHS, and gets added with the $\,\frac{zp}{c} m(r-1)\,$ from the RHS.

Comment: @dxiv I know you are correct, but I get $m_r=zgox^{r-1}+\frac{zp}{c}b+\frac{zp}{c}m_{r-1}-zfy^{r-1}+m_{r-1}$. I am sure this must be simple, but I am not strong in math. Could you explain how you got the addition and subtraction in different order and further explain how $\frac{zp}{c}m(r-1) $ became $(\frac{zp}{c}+1)m_{r-1}$?

Comment: @user3147682 The order doesn't matter for additions and subtractions. Then group ("collect") the two terms in $m_{r-1}$ and you get $\frac{zp}{c}m_{r-1}+m_{r-1}=\left(\frac{zp}{c}+1\right)m_{r-1}$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the closed form... Following the comments, let $m_r = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{r}n(i)$. We have $m_0 = 0$ and, for $r > 0$,
$$m_r = Am_{r - 1} + Bx^{r - 1} + Cy^{r - 1} + D, \quad\text{where}\quad A = 1 + \frac{zp}{c}, B = zgo, C = -zf, D = \frac{zpb}{c}.$$

For real $X, Y$ and integer $r > 0$, the function $T_r(X, Y) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{X^r - Y^r}{X - Y} & (X \neq Y) \\ \hfill r X^{r - 1} & (X = Y)\end{cases}$ satisfies
$$T_0(X, Y) := 0\quad\text{and}\quad T_r(X, Y) = XT_{r - 1}(X, Y) + Y^{r - 1}\quad\text{for}\quad r > 0.$$
This allows to prove (using induction on $r$) that $m_r = BT_r(A, x) + CT_r(A, y) + DT_r(A, 1)$.

Finally, the answer is $n(r) = m_r - m_{r - 1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, im unsure where t came from? What is t?

Comment: Doesnt $$n(r) = m_r - m_{r - 1}$$ require me to find $$m_r$$ and repeat the whole process?

Comment: Introducing a variable $t$ is just a constituent of the [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) approach. The above gives you an _explicit_ formula for $m_r$ (and thus for $m_{r - 1}$, and thus finally for $n(r)$), expressed through $T_r$ (which are also given explicit). For a step-by-step justification, we should probably go into a chat - I admit the above to be too brief.

Comment: How would we go about entering a chat? I tried chat.stackexchange..

Comment: Appears I can't invite you (due to your reputation value). So "feel free" to ask questions here in the comments, in sequence ('til hammers drop down over our heads...). But first try to get it yourself ;)

Comment: LOL! Thanks. And thanks for the previous clarification. Will try to reading through this topic to my threshold of understanding first, before posing any more questions. Will get back to you soon. Thank you.

Comment: I had a 2 hour failed attempt at understanding generating functions. My questions at this point are: What do I insert for T or how do I find T?  What are the commas and how do I use them or what do they connote? What would $m_{r - 1}$ be ?

Comment: I've reformulated the answer (to get rid of generating functions). Regarding $T_r$ - now I'm _defining_ it with the (same) formula that is supposed to be used for calculations. As for $m_{r - 1}$, your question is confusing me - just substitute $r - 1$ for $r$...

Comment: Thank you. So in $T_r(A,x)$ do I replace A for X and x for Y in $T_r(x,y)$. Such that
$$T_r(X, Y) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{X^r - Y^r}{X - Y} & (X \neq Y) \\ \hfill r X^{r - 1} & (X = Y)\end{cases}$$ becomes $$T_r(A, x) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{A^r - x^r}{A - x} & (A \neq x) \\ \hfill r A^{r - 1} & (A = x)\end{cases}$$
? What do I do with the number under the fraction $rX(r−1)$?

Comment: Exactly. The "number under the fraction" is the case $X = Y$ (in which the fraction is $0/0$), so if it happens that $A = x$ (say), you need to use it instead. This is the very reason to introduce $T_r$ at all - writing out $n(r)$ with all case distinctions would consume a wasteful page of text.

Comment: So if $(X \neq Y)$, I would use: $$T_r(X, Y) =\frac{X^r - Y^r}{X - Y}$$ and if $X=Y$, I would use: $$r X^{r-1}$$ instead?

Comment: Yep. $T_r(X, Y) = \displaystyle\frac{X^r - Y^r}{X - Y}$ for $X \neq Y$, and $T_r(X, X) = rX^{r - 1}$. And (for literalism) $T_0(X, Y) = 0$ for any $X, Y$.

Comment: Alright! Thanks! So if $$m_r=BT_r(A, x) + CT_r(A, y) + DT_r(A, 1)$$ is $$m_{r-1}=(BT_r(A, x) + CT_r(A, y) + DT_r(A, 1))-1$$ ?

Comment: No!!! $m_{r - 1} = BT_{r - 1}(A, x) + CT_{r - 1}(A, y) + DT_{r - 1}(A, 1)$. Literally: substitute $r - 1$ for $r$.

Comment: HAHA! lol. Thanks. Will plug this all in to see if its working out.

Comment: A final note (I hope) - this answer is on what a "closed form" for $n(r)$ might be. It is not on how to compute it best; the answer on this latter question depends on many other things - how large $r$ is, what is the computation model with all the costs of operations (in particular, whether raising into $r$-th power is cheaper than just doing multiplications), etc.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. So I have gone through inputting the numbers, it seems the formula works for r=1, but not for r>1. I have attached a google sheet with my results, I wrote a script for Tr in google script editor. Here is the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KCkBTZk22Qi9AIrTsbUMSl1DR_AXqthbULX_AQNZ4MI/edit?usp=sharing   and here is the function https://pastebin.com/fTSx8yX8.

Comment: Fix your $A$ (it is $1 + \displaystyle\frac{zp}{c}$, not $1 + zp$).

Comment: WOW! You are amazing. Bravo!

Comment: My only question at this point is how you arrived at 1+zp/c?

Comment: This is done by @dxiv in his comments to the OP.

Comment: how did you know to create the function Tr, and how did you know to place the variables where you did in the final equation?

Comment: This comes from the linearity of solutions to linear recurrences. On the productive side, for me it was the generating functions approach - the GF for $m_r$ is the sum of $3$ similar terms, and $T_r$ appeared as coefficients of the power series expansion of (the general form of each of the) terms.